# Newton's 1st law and gravity's influence

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction, free-body-diagram

If an object, say a car, is rolling totally frictionless on a flat surface, is the gravity (perpendicular to the car's vector) still slowing it down, i.e., interfering with Newton's 1st law? Or will it maintain its initial speed forever?

Comment: From your setup it seems like gravity is acting perpendicular to the direction of motion, hence, it does not contribute anything into the equation of motion for that car.

Comment: Is it rolling, or is it totally frictionless?  Totally frictionless would imply sliding unless the wheels were already spinning when it came in contact with the frictionless surface.

Answer (score 2):

**Ideally, the initial speed will be maintained forever, yes.** Newton's laws can be split into component directions with each dimension distinctly separated from the others - what happens vertically doesn't influence what happens horizontally.

Vertically, by the way, the speed is also constant. It is constantly zero. Gravity is balanced exactly by the normal force.

Now, in realistic scenarios here at Earth, the speed will of course not be maintained forever. Anything rolling will stop sooner or later. But this is not due to gravity - rather, this is due to axle friction, soft rubber, soft surface etc. all of which suck out energy of the motion.

Answer (score 1):

The car will eventually stop. This is because the rotating  tyre is not truly round. Rather it is a bit flat in the portion where it touches the ground. Now you can see that the contact force given by the ground to the wheel and it's own weight will have an opposite torque on the wheel (if it was previously rotating in the clockwise direction). Thus the car eventually stops.